# How to implement triple or more segment navigation in OData 4

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I'm working on rest serivce with OData v4 protocol using olingo. I got stack on navigation when i'v got let's say:

Company.svc/Departaments(x)/Employees(x)/BussinesTrips

In Olingo's tutorial there is an example where is 2 segments navigation. Where first segment is UriResourceEntitySet and second is UriResourceNavigation.
In the example, these two (especialy entitySet) are needed as parameters in method which gets related entity collection from storage.

In my example there is Company.svc/UriResourceEntitySet/UriResourceNavigation/UriResourceNavigation, what i can say from UriInfo parameter.

I'v no clue how to do that. Should i change the method or somehow force the penulimate segment to be EntitySet.

Thanks for intrest, and im wait for callback.

```
@Override
public void readEntityCollection(ODataRequest request, ODataResponse response, UriInfo uriInfo, ContentType responseFormat)
        throws ODataApplicationException, ODataLibraryException {
    String lastUri = "lastUriResource";
    String sourceNavigationUri = "sourceUriResource";

    EdmEntitySet responseEntitySet = null;
    EntityCollection responseEntityCollection = null;

    List<UriResource> resourcePaths = uriInfo.getUriResourceParts();
    UriResource uriResource = resourcePaths.get(0);
    if (!(uriResource instanceof UriResourceEntitySet)) {
        throw new ODataApplicationException("Only EntitySet is supported", HttpStatusCode.NOT_IMPLEMENTED.getStatusCode(), Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    UriResourceEntitySet uriResourceEntitySet = (UriResourceEntitySet) uriResource;
    EdmEntitySet startEntitySet = uriResourceEntitySet.getEntitySet();
    if (resourcePaths.size() == 1) {
        responseEntitySet = startEntitySet;
        responseEntityCollection = storage.readEntitySetData(responseEntitySet);
    } else {
        startEntitySet = Util.getNavigationTargetEntitySet(uriInfo);
        HashMap<String, UriResource> uriResourceHashMap = Util.getLastNavigationAndItsSource(uriInfo);
        UriResource lastUriResource = uriResourceHashMap.get(lastUri);
        UriResource sourceUriResource = uriResourceHashMap.get(sourceNavigationUri);
        EdmNavigationProperty edmNavigationProperty = null;
        if (!(lastUriResource instanceof UriResourceNavigation)) {
            throw new ODataApplicationException("Only navigation is supported", HttpStatusCode.NOT_IMPLEMENTED.getStatusCode(), Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        edmNavigationProperty = ((UriResourceNavigation) lastUriResource).getProperty();

        if (!(sourceUriResource instanceof UriResourceEntitySet)) {
            throw new ODataApplicationException("Only Entity Set is supported", HttpStatusCode.NOT_IMPLEMENTED.getStatusCode(), Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        uriResourceEntitySet = (UriResourceEntitySet) sourceUriResource;
        startEntitySet = uriResourceEntitySet.getEntitySet();
        responseEntitySet = Util.getNavigationTargetEntitySet(uriInfo);
        EdmEntityType targetEntityType = edmNavigationProperty.getType();
        List<UriParameter> keyParameters = uriResourceEntitySet.getKeyPredicates();

        Entity sourceEntity = storage.readEntityData(startEntitySet, keyParameters);
        if (sourceEntity == null) {
            throw new ODataApplicationException("Entity not found", HttpStatusCode.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode(), Locale.ROOT);
        }
        responseEntityCollection = storage.getRelatedEntityCollection(sourceEntity, targetEntityType);
    }

    ContextURL contextUrl = ContextURL.with().entitySet(responseEntitySet).build();

    final String id = request.getRawBaseUri() + "/" + responseEntitySet.getName();
    EntityCollectionSerializerOptions options = EntityCollectionSerializerOptions.with().id(id).contextURL(contextUrl).build();
    EdmEntityType edmEntityType = responseEntitySet.getEntityType();

    ODataSerializer serializer = odata.createSerializer(responseFormat);
    SerializerResult serializerResult = serializer.entityCollection(serviceMetaData, edmEntityType, responseEntityCollection, options);
    InputStream inputStream = serializerResult.getContent();

    response.setContent(inputStream);
    response.setHeader(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, responseFormat.toContentTypeString());
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK.getStatusCode());

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

*Departaments(x)* is `UriResourceEntitySet`. You probably got its `EdmEntitySet`. Let's say it is stored in `prevEdmEntitySet` variable.

*Employees(x)* is `UriResourceNavigation`. You should take its name and use it with the variable mentioned above:

```
String propName = uriResourceNavigation.getProperty().getName();
EdmEntitySet currEdmEntitySet = (EdmEntitySet) startEdmEntitySet.getRelatedBindingTarget(propName);
```

Then you should start the next iteration with `prevEdmEntitySet=currEdmEntitySet` and repeat for all the `UriResourceNavigation`s (just one more time in your example).